# HTTP headers are not being changed: yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am using yii2 and apache for my server. When I try to change HTTP headers, nothing changes.

```
Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Pragma', 'cache');
```

The default `Pragma: no-cache` remains. This is both on my controller or configuration files. I have tried a suggestion to change headers directly using

```
headers("Pragma: cache");
```

This works perfectly, what might be the issue when using Response class in Yii2?

Comment: Does it work when you use PHP traditional `header("Pragma: cache");` usage ?

Comment: @Cédric thanks a lot for that, I had not used it before and yes it works. Let me update my question accordingly since the problem must be the framework.

Comment: @learner Are you sure that you don't get any error message? have you added `use Yii;`?

Comment: @AliMasudianPour no errors and Yes I am using `Yii` main class

Answer (score 2):

you must before changing header, set `format` property in response class.

in yii2 manual :

> FORMAT_RAW: the data will be treated as the response content without
>   any conversion. **No extra HTTP header will be added**.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html#$format-detail

example :

```
Yii::$app->response->format = yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Pragma', 'cache');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have another code that is modifying the header (explicitly or implicitly). Checking the [HeaderCollection](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/HeaderCollection.php) class, I don't see any reason why it should not work. So check the code after the posted line and see that it does not modify the same header.

Without you posting the relevant code, and stating Yii2 version, this is the best I can do to help!